# Executing tasks with celery at periodic schedule

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to execute a task with celery in Django.I want to execute the task at 12:30 pm everyday for which I have written this in my tasks.py

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=30, hour=12), name="elast")
def elast():
        do something
```

This is not working but if I want to schedule it at every 30 seconds I write this code

```
@periodic_task(run_every=(timedelta(seconds=30)), name="elast")
def elast():
        do something
```

This works.I wanted to know that what is wrong with the first piece of code?Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you running celery beat? And have you considered timezone configuration when validating?

Comment: Running celery beat with this  command celery -A proj -B and I have set CELERY_TIMEZONE in my settings.py

Answer (score 9):

As per latest celery 4.3 version , to execute the task at 12:30 pm below code will be useful
**celery.py**

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    # Executes every day at  12:30 pm.
    'run-every-afternoon': {
        'task': 'tasks.elast',
        'schedule': crontab(hour=12, minute=30),
        'args': (),
    },
}
```

**tasks.py**

```
import celery
@celery.task
def elast():
    do something
```

**to start celery beat scheduler**
celery -A proj worker -B

**for older version around celery 2.0**

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import periodic_task

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=12, minute=30))
def elast():
    print("code execution started.")
```

please check timezone setting.

[New userguide](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules)

[Old userguide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/2.0-archived/getting-started/periodic-tasks.html)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html), especially the parts specific for Django users. Also note that using `@periodic_task` decorator is deprecated and should be replaced with `beat_schedule` configuration (see the [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b2668607c909c61becd151905b4525190c19ff4a/celery/task/base.py#L275)).